# Redirect Hardcoded URLs .htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, url-rewriting, xampp

I have a very old website and it's written in plain HTML. The website used to be hosted publicly, however I downloaded an archive and I now only need it on my localhost (XAMPP) environment.

I had a look at the website code and every link is hardcoded and begins with `http://example.com`. The site contains thousands of links e.g.;

```
http://example.com/category/
http://example.com/category/item
http://example.com/category/item/details/item123.html
etc
```

What's the most efficient way for me to replace all of the links beginning with `http://example.com/` with `localhost`

I could use find and replace but should I instead use a `.htaccess`?

I should add that the domain `http://example.com` no longer exists and I have no access the the hosting etc.

So for example if I click a link that's hardcoded to `http://example.com/category/item/details/item123.html` it should go to `http://localhost/category/item/details/item123.html`

Comment: You would have to have access to `example.com` in the first place, so that you _could_ place a .htaccess file there. And then every single request you make, would cause a request to that online site first, only to redirect back to your localhost - probably not the best idea, performance-wise.

Comment: Alternatively, you could of course add a local virtual host for `example.com`, and have your local DNS resolve that address to your local IP. But then you would of course not be able to reach the "live" version of `example.com` from that system any more, plus it might cause confusion at some future point, when you forget about this and _think_ you were actually operating on the live site, when in fact you aren't ...

Comment: Simply use a file replacement utility, kfilereplace for example. Or import the site as a project into a IDE and use the "global search and replace" feature in there. You probably want to change those links to _relative_ references now.